# Rails migrations with multiple instances

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

We run a few instances of our main application (incidentally across multiple clusters with docker swarm but this is probably not relevant) along with a separate postgreSQL container. 
We..

- Added a migration that creates a new column on a table (JSONB).
- Added application code that whitelists the new attribute so it is included in mass assignment.
- Deployed the new code
- Ran the migration inside one of the instances.

Normally, we'd do a rolling restart of our instances but in this case we had a look to see how the app would respond when contacting a different instance.
What it did was **silently** fail to persist the new attribute. The immediate 201 status JSON response included the attribute but it had in fact not been persisted.

Restarting the instances fixed that but why would rails not raise an exception or even a validation error?

Comment: I'm not sure about what you are asking, but may it because a restart is needed when adding new attributes... since the table columns are cached by ActiveRecord. It is hard to know without seeing any code.

Comment: As far as rails is concerned you are just adding an attribute that isn't in the db, so it's not doing anything with it. As to why allow this - perhaps you defined a custom setter that uses this param to do some pre save logic? Rails can't know for sure I think.

Comment: @Kris this was my thought. However, a silent rather than loud failure seems like a bug.

Comment: @Joel_Blum yes, a custom setter or an `attr_writer` would explain it but there is no such code. An attribute for it must have been generated by the column definition or it would have complained.

Comment: I don't know if this behavior is intentional -  I think it is, but you can open in issue if you think it shouldn't be this way.

Comment: I'm speculating, but if this is a bug, which I'm not sure it is since the recommendation is to restart the application after deployment, then I don't think it would be a high priority.

Comment: When it comes to edge case framework bugs I much prefer throwing an error for no good reason or because a deployment recommendation was overlooked over silently discarding (a lot of) user data. In fact, most database architects would see that as a cardinal sin. If I get time I'll try to reproduce in detail and report it.